# How to convert a list of nested dataframes into a count matrix based on common values in the dataframe

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a long list of genes. I have added a toy example below.

output of dput(list1)

```
list(ENDOSS = structure(list(ENDOSS = c("CDKN1C", "SOX6", "TGFB2"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), ENDOSSSD = structure(list(
    ENDOSSSD = c("CDKN1C", "SOX6", "TGFB2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame"), GASTRIN = structure(list(GASTRIN = c("IKBKB", 
"KIT", "SERPINE1")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), 
    METCC = structure(list(METCC = character(0)), row.names = character(0), class = "data.frame"))
```

The toy list looks as so

```
list1
    ENDOSS
         "CDKN1C", "SOX6", "TGFB2" 
    ENDOSSSD
         "CDKN1C", "SOX6", "TGFB2"
    GASTRIN
          "IKBKB", "KIT", "SERPINE1"
    METCC
```

I would like to transform this list into a count matrix. Based on the example, the output should look like this.

```
             CDKN1C  IKBKB  KIT SERPINE1 SOX6   TGFB2 
    ENDOSS     1       0     0     0       1      1

    ENDOSSSD   1       0     0     0       1      1

    GASTRIN    0       1     1     1       0      0

    METCC      0       0     0     0       0      0
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to combine list of dataframe into one using `bind_rows`, get the data in long format so that all the values are in same column. From here, you can get it back in wide format with it's counts.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(list1, .id = 'name') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = NULL, 
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = value, 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

#   name     CDKN1C  SOX6 TGFB2 IKBKB   KIT SERPINE1
#  <chr>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>    <int>
#1 ENDOSS        1     1     1     0     0        0
#2 ENDOSSSD      1     1     1     0     0        0
#3 GASTRIN       0     0     0     1     1        1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`mtabulate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qdapTools/versions/1.3.5/topics/mtabulate) after converting the column to a vector in each of the `list` elements

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(lapply(list1, unlist))
         CDKN1C IKBKB KIT SERPINE1 SOX6 TGFB2
ENDOSS        1     0   0        0    1     1
ENDOSSSD      1     0   0        0    1     1
GASTRIN       0     1   1        1    0     0
METCC         0     0   0        0    0     0
```